# should we close the connection of a pre-flight Cors request while sending response?

Tags: ajax, http-headers, cors, preflight

As I know that if cors request comes with some extra headers set, first server needs to process it.

With CORS, the server must send the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header to allow uncommon request headers from the client.

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers ... - Comma-delimited list of the supported request headers.**

e.g suppose my pre-flight request is

```
OPTIONS /cors HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://api.bob.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Custom-Header
Host: api.alice.com
Accept-Language: en-US
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0...
```

Then from server-side I will send response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://api.bob.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

My question is - 
should I close the connection on server side while we send pre-flight response to client?

One more thing how can I cached pre-flight request for all other distinct subsequent requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cache the OPTIONS request using the

> Access-Control-Max-Age

header.
Attach it to the headers collection of the OPTIONS response.

But nevertheless an initial OPTIONS request by the user agent (browser) has to be made, you cannot avoid this.
But all further OPTIONS requests are cached and not issued to the server.
No need to close the connection.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://hello-world.example
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT

as explained [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), search for

> could have the following headers specified

to get to the designated text section.

Comment: other distinct subsequent requests will again ask for preflight request with Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: You cannot cache the initial distinct request upfront, only further OPTION requests of the distinct one's. It's a browser thing.

Comment: This is the answer, no other workaround possible :-)

Comment: So If you have 50 rest end points then you will have to send 100 requests.

Comment: Initially yes, subsequent only do one request without a second Option request, if you cache the OPTION request as explained above.

Comment: I see I have no OPTION other than caching the OPTION.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have a lot of GET requests with  frequently changing query parameter values, every new GET request will result in two requests.
What I do, in my web api for example, I have a Messagehandler where i validate the OPTION request and send a 200 response back immediately if it is ok.